# How to scrape a live java script webpage in R?

Tags: javascript, r, web-scraping, css-selectors

I would like to scrape the play by play from http://stats.statbroadcast.com/statmonitr/?id=107165. The link will bring you to the "Split Box" tab. I am interested in scraping the play by play tab as well as the home stats and the visitors stats tab. One of the problems is that no matter what tab you switch to the url never changes. If you use selector gadget the css-selector for the main contents of all the tabs are the same as well, which is "#stats". I am a novice at web scraping and most of the time I can successfully scrape a html page with the package `rvest`, but I am unfortunately lost as to how I should proceed with javascript. I have heard of JSON, but I am not sure how to combat the issue of all the tabs having the same url.

My main goal is to be able to scrape the play by play, home stats, and visitor stats tab when the game is live.

Any help would be much appreciated. Please let me know if I should provide more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `RSelenuim` to do that as follows:

```
require(RSelenium)
RSelenium::startServer()
remDr <- remoteDriver()
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate("http://stats.statbroadcast.com/statmonitr/?id=107165")
```

Now a firefox window should open where you can browse just like normal.
`doc <- remDr$getPageSource()` gives you the Source-Code of the current webpage. You can use `rvest` to scrape this Code as follows:

```
doc <- remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]
require(rvest)
current_doc <- read_html(doc)
```

If you want to automate the "browsing" you can eg. navigate to the "Play by Play"-Page as follows:

```
webElem <- remDr$findElement(using = "css selector", '#bb_b6')
remDr$mouseMoveToLocation(webElement = webElem)
remDr$click(1)
```

At the end: close the remote driver ans shut down selenium-server

```
#shutdown
remDr$close()
browseURL("http://localhost:4444/selenium-server/driver/?cmd=shutDownSeleniumServer")
```

For more details see:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/vignettes/RSelenium-basics.html

**Edit:**
`current_doc` caputures the website as it is when you execute `doc <- remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]`. It is NOT a realtime like. It is a 1 time picture.

If you want to scrape "Period I" do as follows:
1st navigate to "Play by Play" (as shown above) - `Sys.sleep(3)` till the website is loaded - Then navigate to "Period I" the same way you navigated to "Play by Play" just with another css-selector.

Have a look at your remote-driver (aka the browser window you control) if you arrived at the "Period I" webpage.

After you arrived execute `doc <- remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]` and analyse the content.

Comment: Thanks so much this worked great. I do have a follow question. When I inspect the element I can easily see that css selector for the tab "play by play", which as you stated is #bb_b6, but that will lead me to play play play's "MOST RECENT" TAB. I would like to find the selector for "PERIOD ONE"  and "PERIOD TWO". I have tried this code. `current_doc <- html_nodes(current_doc, "#stats > div:nth-child(3) > div.sbmodule.ui-widget > div.ui-widget-header > a:nth-child(2) > span")`, but this just prints "PERIOD ONE'.   Thank you again for your help.

Comment: `webElem <- remDr$findElement(using = "css selector", '#bb_b6')
remDr$mouseMoveToLocation(webElement = webElem)
remDr$click(1)



doc <- remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]
require(rvest)
current_doc <- read_html(doc)
current_doc <- html_nodes(current_doc, "#stats > div:nth-child(3) > div.sbmodule.ui-widget > div.ui-widget-header > a:nth-child(2) > span")
playbyplay <- html_text(current_doc)` I thought it might help you to see more of the code I used.

Comment: See my edit. `doc <- remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]` DOES NOT CREATE A REALTIME SOURCECODE PICTURE: IT IS A SNAPSHOT OF YOUR BROWSERS SOURCECODE