# rvest HTML table scrape is empty

Tags: html, r, rvest

I'm trying to scrape a table, but the results are empty. While html_nodes("table") recognizes two tables, specifying with "[1]" is just the headers for the table, and "[2]" is a data frame of the correct dimensions, containing only NA's. I've used this same code for tables in other places from the same site, and they work fine. In fact, this code worked for me until this week. There are no errors output when running this code and I can't seem to find anything unusual about the HTML file itself (no missing tags or anything), but I'm not terribly familiar with HTML files so I could be missing something. Here is my code:

```
    Vegas_lines_html <- read_html("https://rotogrinders.com/schedules/nba")
    Vegas_lines <- Vegas_lines_html %>% 
    html_nodes("table") %>% 
    .[[1]] %>%    # here index 1 is only headers, index 2 is the data frame full of NA's
    html_table()
```

Comment: The page content is inserted via JS. This means you have to render the page before extracting the table. Have a look at https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/vignettes/RSelenium-basics.html on how to do this with `rselenium`. Here i described it for a different webpage: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35059060/how-to-scrape-a-live-java-script-webpage-in-r/35060138#35060138

Comment: Might want to read item #3 [here](https://rotogrinders.com/static/terms).

Comment: Thanks, Floo0! That worked perfectly. Also, thanks for sending that my way, hrbrmstr.